# With digital siganture certificate in c# asp.net while clicking on select certificate

Tags: c#, digital-signature

While signing with a digital signature in C# / .NET I am getting this error. Can any body solve this?

> "Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The current
>   session is not interactive."

My code:

```
protected void btnSelectCertificate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
    X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, 
        "Test Certificate Select", "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate", 
        X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
}
```

Comment: the error is self explaining. moreover without any code is not possible to help you.

Comment: I improved your post formatting, but please add additional details so that other users can help you

Comment: protected void btnSelectCertificate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
                   X509Certificate2Collection scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Test Certificate Select", "Select a certificate from the following list to get information on that certificate", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);

Comment: Edit the post to put your code there, not in a comment.